# Resize a file (down)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

I'm attempting to shrink a file in place.
I'm replacing the contents of one file with those of another and when I'm done I want to make sure if the source file is smaller than the dest file, the dest file shrinks correctly.

(Why: because the dest file is a backup and writing to the media is very expensive, so I only write the deltas to the backup)

```
1.) HANDLE hDest =(HANDLE)_get_osfhandle( fileno(backupFile.GetBufferedHandle()) );
2.) DWORD startingSize = GetFileSize(hDest, NULL);
3.) DWORD dwPtr = SetFilePointer(hDest, newSize, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
4.) int err = GetLastError();
5.) if (dwPtr != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
6.) {   err = SetEndOfFile(hDest); 
7.)     if(err == 0) 
8.)         err = GetLastError();
9.)     err = SetFileValidData(hDest, newSize);
10.) }
11.) DWORD endingSize = GetFileSize(hDest, NULL);
```

I'm getting an error on line 8 that is 1224... I'm wondering if anyone can tell me why, or suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"net helpmsg 1224" -> The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.

And from MSDN for [`SetEndOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531(VS.85).aspx):

> If CreateFileMapping is called to
>   create a file mapping object for
>   hFile, UnmapViewOfFile must be called
>   first to unmap all views and call
>   CloseHandle to close the file mapping
>   object before you can call
>   SetEndOfFile.

Comment: Thank you.. Turns out the class that I was using to open the file (a new wheel) was doing some mapping.  When I brought the code down to the base fopen... it worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the "net helpmsg", now I can finally get rid of ERRLOOK.EXE :)

Answer (score 0):

That error translates to `The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.`

Do you have any memory mapped segments of that file?

Comment: I don't think so.. I'm using a custom file library (yeah newly invented wheel).  I guess I'll have to dig.

Answer (score -2):

You got an error code of 0 which means success (ERROR_SUCCESS) and it did work, see line 6 in the sample you provided. Now why did you call a `GetLastError` immediately after the check in line 7? By the way, I think you should be using ERROR_SUCCESS instead of 0. The reference to the error codes can be found [here](http://help.netop.com/support/errorcodes/win32_error_codes.htm). Or did you actually mean it occurred in line 9?

Can you confirm this?
Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: `SetEndOfFile` returns zero on failure. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531%28VS.85%29.aspx.

Comment: @BillyONeal...Whoopsie! My bad!...tis late for me, need sleep...I apologize for my misunderstanding... :( Sorry